# Spring Cloud Data Flow Task database and Single step batch data source pointing to separate external database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm setting up an instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow. I've run the following commands:

java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.9.2.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-test.com:1521/dev --spring.datasource.username=ORACLE_USER --spring.datasource.password=123456 --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver &

In the second step, I'm using some other oracle database, not the dataflow oracle task database.

**How to separate dataflow task datasource and batch job Itemreader/Writer database with two external data source.**

```
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.data-password=123456
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.data-username=ORACLE_USER
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.password=123456
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-test-perf.com:1521/test
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.datasource.username=ORACLE_USER
app.dataflow-single-step-batch.spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

**With this above configuration Batch job ItemReader points to other data source. But I am getting the issue below **
**Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 32 not found**

Comment: Any reason you are trying to separate the databases? Centralizing business tables and technical tables makes your application's configuration easier than having to deal with distributed transactions with JTA, etc. In your case, you need to configure the reader/writer by setting the second datasource on them directly.

Comment: We have application database in different source. Since we have to do some ETL kind of operation where we have to read and write in Oracle to MySQL. Please suggest me the proper configuration so that we can read/write from other external database.

Comment: You can have a Spring Batch job that reads data from a database and writes it to another one. For that, you need to configure two datasources and set them on the reader and the writer as needed. Now for the meta-data, it is up to you to decide where to put the Batch/Task tables.